# $\epsilon$-net of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ supported on an $S^{n-1}$ ball.

Tags: geometry

Consider a unit ball in the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($S^{n-1}$). There exists an $\epsilon$-net with cardinality bounded by $9^n$ if $\epsilon = 1/4$.

I am thinking if we only consider a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, specifically, we have the basis $(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we pick the first $m$ bases with $m<n$ and span the space by these bases (this should be $\mathbb{R}^m$). The intersection between the ball $S^{n-1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ should be a ball $S^{m-1}$. Then there should exist an $\epsilon$-net whose cardinality is bounded by $9^m$. Is it correct?

Comment: How do you define an $\varepsilon$-net? I'm used to it referring to a set of points so that no point in the space is greater than (or possibly greater than or equal to) $\varepsilon$ distance from your set. Under this definition (either variant), you can't prove that an $\varepsilon$-net has any cardinality, as you can always add in more points. Are you trying to show that a $\varepsilon$-net exists with $9^n$ points? Certainly $9^1$ points are not necessary when $n = 1$!

Comment: Good point! I should've said the cardinality of the $\epsilon$-net is bounded by $9^n$.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick here, but you should say "There exists an $\varepsilon$-net of cardinality at most $9^n$", rather than "The cardinality of the $\varepsilon$-net is bounded by $9^n$". It makes it sound like **all** $\varepsilon$-nets on the set are bounded by $9^n$, and given that there can be no universal bound *from above*, it suggests that you're trying to show the universal bound from below is $9^n$ (which, as I pointed out, is not true).

Comment: You are right. Math has to be rigorous. Btw, do you think my claim is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your claim. I don't think that a $1/4$-net in a proper subspace will be a $1/4$-net of the whole sphere, because there are points of distance larger than $1/4$ from the sphere in the subspace (indeed, there'll be points of distance $\sqrt{2}$ away from those net points). If this isn't how you're building your net, then I'm not sure what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful